# Error while installing Visual studio 2013 with update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2012, startup

i'm trying to install visual studio 2013 into my windows 7 32 bit system. I've encountered the below error during installation

```
"This update package could not be opened. Verify that the update package exists and that you can   
access  it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer   
update   package."
```

Help me out

Comment: What download url did you use?  Did they give you a hash to verify that the image or file is not corrupt?

Comment: Do you have the complete install package?  Or, the update 3 install only?

Answer (score 0):

it is windows so i am guessing: the installer package is corrupt or follow this link: http://kb.eset.de/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN561

try to make some md5 sums of your files and google for them.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this issue will occur if you are having permission issue or compatibility issue.

**For permission issue:**

Right click on the executable and run it with run as administrator option and check.

**If above is not working then check for the compatibility issue by following the steps below:**

To Run the installation program in compatibility mode:
1. Right-click the installation file's icon.
2. Click Properties > Compatibility .
3. Select the compatibility mode for Windows XP.
4. Click OK .
5. Run the installation program.
After it's installed, run the program in Windows XP compatibility mode by doing the same with the installed program.
If you have an older application for Windows XP or Vista that doesn't run in Windows 7, you may be able to get it working properly by running the program in compatibility mode.
1. To begin, find the application or shortcut that is causing the problem, then right click on it and select Properties.
2. Then, select Compatibility from the tabbed menu at the top of the properties page:
3. Now, check the "Run this program in compatibility mode for..." box and select the OS you wish to emulate. For most applications, it will be Windows XP SP2. Once you are done, click OK.
4. When you next launch the application it should run under compatibility mode using the OS you selected. If it still fails to run correctly, try another OS selection in step 3 and try again.